# Перехват всех исключений в приложении на Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Появилась проблемка с перехватом исключений в middleware. Допустим я подключил вот такую:

```
import traceback
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class ExcMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    @staticmethod
    def process_exception(request, exc): 
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

И когда в какой нибудь view происходит исключительная ситуация, то все проходит как и было задумано.

Но вот, например, если я допустим в своем urls.py допущу ошибку:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

import error_app.views as root_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', root_views.home, 'home'), # тут надо name='home'
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

IDE выдает следующий traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roast/.virtualenvs/notice_error/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/roast/.virtualenvs/notice_error/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 101, in _get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/home/roast/.virtualenvs/notice_error/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "/home/roast/.virtualenvs/notice_error/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
    kwargs.update(self.default_args)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Но в созданной middleware ничего не происходит. Видать я не совсем понимаю как это работает. Есть у кого-нибудь соображения по этому поводу? И что нужно делать чтобы получить доступ к tracback всех исключений, которые выбрасывает django приложение?

Comment: urls/resolvers работает раньше чем подключенна мидлварь

Comment: Хорошо, где тогда перехватывать вот такие исключения, которые могут возникнуть раньше, чем вызовется мидлварь?

Comment: Если я все правильно понимаю, то нужно пилить какую-то надстройку над wsgi application.

Comment: try: app = application() прямо тут

Comment: Если провалиться в коде начиная с файла wsgi.py по цепочке get_wsgi_application -> WSGIHandler, то в WSGIHandler в методе __call__ перед возвратом response импортится traceback зачем-то. Я написал после импорта print(traceback.format_exc()), в консоли получил NoneType: None. Не понятно

Comment: try: app = application() не работает

Comment: это направление, а не инструкции

Comment: ну я оборачивал в try вот это application = get_wsgi_application().